# How to access only in built finger print scanner in android and not using Android KeyStore

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I need to access inbuilt fingerprint scanner in android and generate a key and i need to map with my database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by _"access inbuilt fingerprint scanner"_. The functionality you can use is the one provided by the official APIs. You cannot get the actual fingerprint data, if that's what you're after. Even the OS doesn't have access to that.

Comment: if it is not accessible means, if there are five finger print of different person on a same device is it possible to find who accessing the phone?